# NavMeshAgent could not be set properly on imported 3d model in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am trying to set NavMeshAgent on imported 3D model in unity 3d but the navMeshAgent couldnot be set properly around my 3d model. If I extend the radius it covers unuseful part more than the 3d object.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve the problem the problem is to create an Empty Object in Unity and then set the 3D Model as the child of the Empty Gameobject. This by default make the center aligned and when you set the NavMeshAgent it will be set from the center of your gameobject.